# table columns in epub reader mobile application is overlapping in next page

Tags: css, epub

I am trying to fix a tricky problem where the table columns move to the next page in mobile application. Note it is in epub format.

Image below: - [image: epub view in mobile][image: epub]
[image: epub mobile view]

With above images you might get how it is breaking. I have tried few css props which are break-inside, overflow-x: scroll, display:table, but nothing works. And when i did display:block or dispay:grid the tables didn't pass into next page but only showed rows till length of screen. I am stuck in this and feels tricky. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```css
CSS
------
@charset "utf-8";
/* Styles for Copy of Magezine August 2023.docx */
:root {
--primary: #264d7e;        
--light-txt: #ffffff; /light shades/
--article-txt: #fb5858; /gray shades/
--body-txt: #2f2f2f;
}


body {
  font-family: "Helvetica", Sans-Serif;
  color: var(--body-txt);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

legend{
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  word-spacing: 0.4px;
  color: var(--primary);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: underline;  
  text-decoration: italic;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 33px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  word-spacing: 0.4px;
  color: var(--primary);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: underline overline;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: center;
}

h2{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: var(--light-txt);
  background-color: var(--primary);
  text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 2px 2px 2px;
  padding:4px;
}

h3{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--primary);
  margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.img-responsive {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:10px solid;  
    border-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px -25px 20px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), 0px 25px 20px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);  
}


 ul {
      list-style: none;
       margin-top:5px;
       line-height: 1.2;
    }
ul li::before {
      content: "\2022";
      color: var(--primary);          
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1em;
      margin-left: -1.2em;
      margin-right: 0 px;
      font-size: 150%;

    }

 ol {
   list-style: none;
   margin-top:5px;  
   counter-reset: item;
   margin-left: -30px;
   line-height: 1.2;

 }
  ol li {
   counter-increment: item;
   margin-bottom: 5px;  
 }
 ol li:before {
   margin-right: 5px;  
   content: counter(item)".";
   font-weight: bold;  
   color: var(--primary);
 }
 
p{
  margin-top:5px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
line-height: 1.2;
 
}

article{
  font-size:14px;
  font-style:italic;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
  color: red;
}

#test {
  color: 'green';
  background-color: "yellow";
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

table {
    font-size:11px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: hidden;
    border: 1px solid var(--primary);
    width: 50px;
   
 
}
table td {
  padding: 0.3rem;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary);
}
table th {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color:var(--light-txt);
}
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops"><head>
  <title>Unknown</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="page_styles.css"/>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="toc_1">12. MISSPELT</h1>
<table epub:type="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>S.No.</th>
<th>Incorrect</th>
<th>Correct</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1.</td>
<td>Injecshun</td>
<td>Injection</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2.</td>
<td>Restaurent </td>
<td>Restaurant</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3.</td>
<td>Wittnes</td>
<td>Witness</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4.</td>
<td>Changeuble</td>
<td>Changeable</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5.</td>
<td>Bouquat</td>
<td>Bouquet</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6.</td>
<td>Aggresive</td>
<td>Aggressive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7.</td>
<td>Vizibility</td>
<td>Visibility</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8.</td>
<td>Avalaunche</td>
<td>Avalanche</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9.</td>
<td>Impecable</td>
<td>Impeccable</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10.</td>
<td>Squirrell</td>
<td>Squirrel</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11.</td>
<td>Commiety</td>
<td>Committee</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12.</td>
<td>Beizarre</td>
<td>Bizarre</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13.</td>
<td>Stridancy</td>
<td>Stridency</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14.</td>
<td>Asassination</td>
<td>Assassination</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15.</td>
<td>Arbittrates</td>
<td> Arbitrate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16.</td>
<td>Percoletion</td>
<td>Percolation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>17.</td>
<td>Impovarish</td>
<td> Impoverish</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>18.</td>
<td>Floresecent</td>
<td>Fluorescent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>19.</td>
<td>Daclination</td>
<td>Declination</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20.</td>
<td>Coniferos</td>
<td>Coniferous</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21.</td>
<td>Curosity</td>
<td>Curiosity</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22.</td>
<td>Obsesiv</td>
<td>Obsessive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>23.</td>
<td>Imunize</td>
<td>Immunise</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>24.</td>
<td>Distilation</td>
<td>Distillation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>25.</td>
<td>Contursion</td>
<td>Contortion</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>26.</td>
<td>Aggrresion</td>
<td>Aggression</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>27.</td>
<td>Glamerous</td>
<td>Glamorous</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>28.</td>
<td>Arogance</td>
<td>Arrogance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>29.</td>
<td>Laison</td>
<td>Liaison</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>30.</td>
<td>Foresable</td>
<td>Foreseeable</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>31.</td>
<td>Culleague</td>
<td>Colleague</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>32.</td>
<td>Farenheit</td>
<td>Fahrenheit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>33.</td>
<td>Humourosu</td>
<td>Humorous</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>34.</td>
<td>Proximmat</td>
<td>Proximate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>35.</td>
<td>Arogance</td>
<td>Arrogance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>36.</td>
<td>Irresistable</td>
<td>Irresistible</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>37.</td>
<td>Raveshing</td>
<td>Ravishing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>38.</td>
<td>Mellnia</td>
<td>Millennia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>39.</td>
<td>Declenasion</td>
<td>Declination</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>40.</td>
<td>Prrefored</td>
<td>Preferred</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>41.</td>
<td>Exacerbat</td>
<td>Exacerbate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12.</td>
<td>Forien</td>
<td>Foreign</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>43.</td>
<td>Recuparate</td>
<td>Recuperate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>44.</td>
<td>Eshilariate</td>
<td>Experience</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>45.</td>
<td>Meritocretic</td>
<td>Meritocratic </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>46.</td>
<td>Monnopolly</td>
<td>Monopoly</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>47.</td>
<td>Misichievous</td>
<td>Mischievous</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>48.</td>
<td>Protubarance</td>
<td>Protuberance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>49.</td>
<td>Ambarass</td>
<td>Embarrass</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>50</td>
<td>Repositary</td>
<td>Repository</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>51.</td>
<td>Heirarchy</td>
<td>Hierarchy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>52.</td>
<td>Ocurrense</td>
<td>Occurrence</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>53.</td>
<td>Stareotype</td>
<td>Stereotype</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>54.</td>
<td>Gratifyeing</td>
<td>Gratifying</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>55.</td>
<td>Immpenetrable</td>
<td>Impenetrable</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>56.</td>
<td>Honoraery</td>
<td>Honorary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>57.</td>
<td>Pharoar</td>
<td>Pharaoh</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>58.</td>
<td>Minoscole</td>
<td>Minuscule</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>60.</td>
<td>Exuberrantly</td>
<td>Exuberantly </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>61.</td>
<td>Inunndate</td>
<td>Inundate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>62.</td>
<td>Benefecial</td>
<td>Beneficial</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>63.</td>
<td>Perrume</td>
<td>Presume</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>64.</td>
<td>Scrupulus</td>
<td>Scrupulous</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>65.</td>
<td>Qustionnaire</td>
<td>Questionnaire</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>66.</td>
<td>Fasefication</td>
<td>Falsification</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>67.</td>
<td>Meidieval</td>
<td>Medieval</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>68.</td>
<td>Sergent</td>
<td>Sergeant</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>69.</td>
<td>Effuzively</td>
<td>Effusively</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>70.</td>
<td>Illiterrate</td>
<td>Illiterate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>71.</td>
<td>Vaccuumm</td>
<td>vacuum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>72.</td>
<td>Petronage</td>
<td>Patronage</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>73.</td>
<td>Cameousflage</td>
<td>Camouflage</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>74.</td>
<td>Scentillate</td>
<td>Scintillate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>75.</td>
<td>Hibarnate</td>
<td>Hibernate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>76.</td>
<td>Idoeosyncrasy</td>
<td>Idiosyncrasy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>77.</td>
<td>Raeferred</td>
<td>Referred</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>78.</td>
<td>Anunceation</td>
<td>Annunciation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>79.</td>
<td>Inocculate</td>
<td>Inoculate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>80.</td>
<td>Megallomaniac </td>
<td>Megalomaniac</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>81.</td>
<td>Orientasion</td>
<td>Orientation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>82</td>
<td>Acuainatance</td>
<td>Acquaintance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>83.</td>
<td>Immiediatley</td>
<td>Immediately</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>84.</td>
<td>Anotate</td>
<td>Annotate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>85.</td>
<td>Conjecturel</td>
<td>Conjectural</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>86</td>
<td>Apparant</td>
<td>Apparent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>87.</td>
<td>Apeareance</td>
<td>Appearance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>88.</td>
<td>Guarantiei</td>
<td>Guarantee</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>89.</td>
<td>Desendent</td>
<td>Descendant</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>90.</td>
<td>Misterous</td>
<td>Mysterious</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>91.</td>
<td>Svivelling</td>
<td>Swiveling</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>92.</td>
<td>Acquittied</td>
<td>Acquitted</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>93.</td>
<td>Unatrractiveness</td>
<td>Unattractiveness</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>94.</td>
<td>Caetegory</td>
<td>Category</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>95.</td>
<td>Scintillaters</td>
<td>Scintillators</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>96.</td>
<td>Dielema</td>
<td>Dilemma</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>97.</td>
<td>Constituet</td>
<td>Constitute</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>98.</td>
<td>Promounciation</td>
<td>Pronunciation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>99.</td>
<td>Pronunciation</td>
<td>Bifurcated</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>100</td>
<td>Circumvanting</td>
<td>Circumventing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>101</td>
<td>Sichology</td>
<td>Psychology</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>102</td>
<td>Manineveer</td>
<td>Maneuver </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>103</td>
<td>Expantion</td>
<td>Expansion</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>104</td>
<td>Intellijent</td>
<td>Intelligent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>105</td>
<td>Humanitariaesm</td>
<td>Humanitarianism</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>106</td>
<td>Floundar</td>
<td>Flounder</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>107</td>
<td>Maintainence</td>
<td>Maintenance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>108</td>
<td>Accomeodate</td>
<td>Accommodate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>109</td>
<td>Possetion</td>
<td>Possession</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>110</td>
<td>Valedection</td>
<td>Valediction</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>111</td>
<td>Asyrian</td>
<td>Assyrian</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>112</td>
<td>Iminent</td>
<td>Imminent </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>113</td>
<td>Neoplagm </td>
<td> Neoplasm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>114</td>
<td>Auixiliary</td>
<td>Auxiliary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>115</td>
<td>Frothyest</td>
<td>Frothiest</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>116</td>
<td>Misillaneus</td>
<td>Miscellaneous</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>117</td>
<td>Incommuncabal</td>
<td>Incommunicable</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>118</td>
<td>Exipberamce</td>
<td>Exuberance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>119</td>
<td>Revarberate</td>
<td>Reverberate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>120</td>
<td>Effluants</td>
<td>Effluents</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>121</td>
<td>Symptommatically</td>
<td>Symptomatically</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>122</td>
<td>Orcheistra</td>
<td>Orchestra</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123</td>
<td>Interuption</td>
<td>Interruption</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>124</td>
<td>Imparsonators</td>
<td>Impersonators</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>125</td>
<td>Handkurchief</td>
<td>Handkerchief</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>126</td>
<td>Annexeations</td>
<td>Annexations</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>127</td>
<td>Gorrilla</td>
<td>Guerrilla</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>128</td>
<td>Ceeling</td>
<td>Ceiling</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>129</td>
<td>Forceibly</td>
<td>Forcibly</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>130</td>
<td>Precariousely</td>
<td>Precariously</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>131</td>
<td>Intreference</td>
<td>Interference</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>132</td>
<td>Frenatically</td>
<td>Frenetically</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>133</td>
<td>Disconcerrted</td>
<td>Disconcerted</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>134</td>
<td>Neolethic</td>
<td>Neolithic</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>135</td>
<td>Hygeine</td>
<td>Hygiene</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>136</td>
<td>Controvershial</td>
<td>Controversial</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>137</td>
<td>Guardiun</td>
<td>Guardian</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>138</td>
<td>Indespossition</td>
<td>Indisposition</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>139</td>
<td>Perennialy</td>
<td>Perennially</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>140</td>
<td>Pretansions</td>
<td>Pretensions</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>141</td>
<td>Gimmic</td>
<td>Gimmick</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>142</td>
<td>Fallacoius</td>
<td>Fallacious</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>143</td>
<td>Hotiness</td>
<td> Haughtiness</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>144</td>
<td>Gramar</td>
<td>Grammar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>145</td>
<td>Diseese</td>
<td>Disease</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>146</td>
<td>Encourragemaent</td>
<td>Encouragement</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>147</td>
<td>Bachelar</td>
<td>Bachelor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>148</td>
<td>Newclear</td>
<td>Neuclear</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>149</td>
<td>Hygene</td>
<td>Hygiene</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>150</td>
<td>Exausted</td>
<td>Exhausted</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>151</td>
<td>Geniune</td>
<td>Genuine</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>152</td>
<td>Noticable</td>
<td>Noticeable</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>153</td>
<td>Passinger</td>
<td>Passenger</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>154</td>
<td>Konvenience</td>
<td>Convenience</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>155</td>
<td>Exilarate</td>
<td>Exhilarate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>156</td>
<td>Disccusion </td>
<td>Discussion </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>157</td>
<td>Permmit</td>
<td>Permit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>158</td>
<td>Submision</td>
<td>Submission</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>159</td>
<td>Obbstacle</td>
<td>Obstacle</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>160</td>
<td>Phelosophy</td>
<td>Philosophy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>161</td>
<td>Toungue</td>
<td>Tongue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>162</td>
<td>Queua</td>
<td>Queue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>163</td>
<td>Supplimantry</td>
<td>Supplementary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>164</td>
<td>Lubrisent</td>
<td>Lubricant</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>165</td>
<td>Committe</td>
<td>Committee</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>166</td>
<td>Anniversery</td>
<td>Anniversary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>167</td>
<td>Devlop</td>
<td>Develop</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>168</td>
<td>Discipiline</td>
<td>Discipline</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>169</td>
<td>Tution</td>
<td>Tuition</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>170</td>
<td>Injineer</td>
<td>Engineer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>171</td>
<td>Administrater</td>
<td>Administrator</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>172</td>
<td>Beautifuli</td>
<td>Beautifully</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>173</td>
<td>Rupangence</td>
<td>Repugnance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>174</td>
<td>Restaurent</td>
<td>Restaurant</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>175</td>
<td>Foriegn</td>
<td>Foreign</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>176</td>
<td>Succesful</td>
<td>Successful</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>177</td>
<td>Unfortunetely</td>
<td>Unfortunately</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>178</td>
<td>Outragous</td>
<td>Outrageous </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>179</td>
<td>Maintnance</td>
<td>Maintenance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>180</td>
<td>Tachnique</td>
<td>Technique</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>181</td>
<td>Diamand</td>
<td>Diamond</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>182</td>
<td>Emfasize</td>
<td>Emphasise</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>183</td>
<td>Dielema</td>
<td>Dilemma</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>814</td>
<td>Foraign</td>
<td>Foreign</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>185</td>
<td>Extrawagant</td>
<td>Extravagant</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>186</td>
<td>Corup</td>
<td>Corrupt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>187</td>
<td>Luxeuries</td>
<td>Luxuries</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>188</td>
<td>Colaborate</td>
<td>Collaborate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>189</td>
<td>Lisence</td>
<td>Licence</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>190</td>
<td>Independant</td>
<td>Independent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>191</td>
<td>Definitly</td>
<td>Definitely</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>192</td>
<td>Definitely</td>
<td>Elementary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>193</td>
<td>Moddern</td>
<td>Modern</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>194</td>
<td>Scienctifie</td>
<td>Scientific</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>195</td>
<td>Disgise</td>
<td>Disguise</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>196</td>
<td>Recommand</td>
<td>Recommend</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>197</td>
<td>Godess</td>
<td>Goddess</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>198</td>
<td>Asimilate</td>
<td>Assimilate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>199</td>
<td>Posibilty</td>
<td>Possibility</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>200</td>
<td>Occassion</td>
<td>Occasion</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>201</td>
<td>Feudel</td>
<td>Feudal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>202</td>
<td>Exhoustive</td>
<td>Exhaustive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>203</td>
<td>Patrimonety</td>
<td>Patrimony</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>204</td>
<td>Nocturenal</td>
<td>Nocturnal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>205</td>
<td>Adrress</td>
<td>Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>206</td>
<td>Indivisual</td>
<td>Individual</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>207</td>
<td>Reverense</td>
<td>Reverence</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>208</td>
<td>Inqustive</td>
<td>Inquisitive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>209</td>
<td>Lumeniscent</td>
<td>Luminescent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>210</td>
<td>Welfair</td>
<td>Welfare</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>211</td>
<td>Ettiquete</td>
<td>Etiquette</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you please give details, where exactly this problem is supposed to occur? Using browser dev tools with your rendered snippet, to emulate a narrow screen width, I can't seem to reproduce the issue. _"in mobile application"_ - does this mean anything other than a mobile browser, some sort of specific epub reader app?

Comment: yeah exactly. Inside the real mobile application. I have integrated the epub reader in my native project using skyepub sdk. and seems like the epub is overriding the css properties. display:block makes the whole table in one screen and can't view the table because of screen's height. Also tried inline styling in table and !important but doesn't seem to work.